# Shaping arrays that nested in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple arrays nested in a list:

```
[array([[0.61975185, 0.9286927 , 2.0753862 , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.62096828, 0.92906455, 2.07642053, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.66022333, 0.89742236, 2.2130632 , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        ...,
        [0.45926521, 1.15869818, 1.14577362, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.40854863, 1.16321563, 1.00299252, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.38154862, 1.16117506, 0.92948434, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ]]),
 array([[0.55734019, 0.96495142, 1.88014278, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.55958069, 0.96881081, 1.87070775, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
```

size of the list:

```
len(tau)
```

output:

```
1999
```

each nested arrays have different sizes:

```
tau[12]
```

output

```
array([[0.62197477, 0.92899337, 2.07812452, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.65314345, 0.90680185, 2.17903213, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.61074943, 0.93372645, 2.04839342, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.55673261, 1.04335883, 1.66442397, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.5545177 , 1.04274679, 1.66154383, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.38214755, 1.16130868, 0.93097808, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])
```

and shape

```
tau[12].shape
```

output

```
9, 480
```

more

```
tau[120].shape
```

output:

```
 10, 480
```

etc.

How can I combine all these arrays as

```
np.array((tau[0][0], tau[0][1], tau[0][2], ..., (tau[1][0], tau[1][1], tau[1][2], ...., tau[n][0], tau[n][1], ...))
```

depending of their shapes to create an array with size as their combine for example like

```
19000, 480
```

19000 is basically sum of all shapes of nested arrays

Comment: @9769953 I have corrected it. Please check it again.. dtype is float64

Comment: @Jab I dont wanna remove anything... I just wanna create a 2D array as in the last lines...

Comment: If all arrays are shape (n,480)` you should be able to `concatenate` them (axis 0).  `np.vstack` does this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so. The solutions are ranked by performance.

## Input data

I guess that you have 2d arrays of same length in the second dimension.

```py
import numpy as np

second_dim = 7
# generate the 'tau'
tau = [np.ones((i, second_dim)) * i for i in range(1, 10)]
print([i.shape for i in tau])  # print shapes
# [(1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7)]
```

Now you can append all arrays into a single array along the first dimension in various ways.

## Solutions

### Solution 1: numpy concatenate

```py
np.concatenate(tau, axis=0)
```

### Solution 2: numpy vstack

Based on [hpaulj's input](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

```py
`enter code here`
np.vstack(tau)
```

### Solution 3: list extend

alternatively you can also use `list.extend`

```py
def list_extend(a):
    res = []
    for i in a:
        res.extend(i)
    return np.array(res)
```

### Solution 4: numpy append

Not recommended see [hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj).

```py
def np_append(a):
    res = np.array([]).reshape(0, *a[0].shape[1:])
    for i in range(len(a)):
        res = np.append(res, a[i], axis=0)
    return res

print(np_append(a).shape)
# (45, 7)
```

## Speed testing

Comparing both options list_extend is way faster on my machine (~10 times). However, that can change with the problem.

Tested with:

```py
a = [np.ones((i, 480)) * i for i in range(1, 196)]
# -> np.concatenate(a, axis=0).shape is (19110, 480)

%timeit -n 3 -r 3 np.concatenate(a, axis=0)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 np.vstack(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 list_extend(a)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 np_append(a)

# 20.4 ms ± 575 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each)
# 19.9 ms ± 387 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each)
# 29.5 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each)
# 3.41 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Repeated `np.append` in a loop is a bad idea.  It does not work in-place.  `Did you try `np.vstack(tau)`?

Comment: Why are there two "solution 2"s, and two "list extend"s?

Comment: Since the original dimensions are known, it would be more useful to see timings with those dimensions. In particular, 7 is quite a bit smaller than 480, and the timing of some operations can increase quadratically or worse with larger sizes (or even with large jumps when there are allocation optimisations).

Comment: - "solution 2"s: just a c/p, changed it
- "Since the original dimensions": the target dimensions are know, but not the nested shapes. However, changed it to: `a = [np.ones((i, 480)) * i for i in range(1, 196)]` and updated the timings.